# How to revert Androidone X510 to Lollipop

Tags: android-versions, android-device-manager, android-sdk

I am making use of Androidone,
Model:X510
Version: 5.1.1

Recently, my phone received a system update, so I installed the system update, and my device upgraded to Android Marshmallow 6.0.

After this update, I started having problems with most of my apps. These apps have refused to run.
For example, I installed Modern Combat 4, but after the update, the game doesn't display, it just shows a pink screen.

I have tried everything I could, but I am still having this problem, and there is no way I can contact the manufacturer, because the phone is made by Google.

My main question is this—

How do I uninstall this new update of 6.0, and return my device to its former stage, which is 5.1.1?

Thank you.

Comment: Search for custom ROMs or stock firmware and flash it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help you, maybe it's not relevant to your answer (but I think it's kinda). So, yesterday I've got a little problem too when try to installing Modern Combat 4 on my lollipop device. I downloaded the Modern Combat 4 from this link
http://apksaurus.com/modern-combat-4-android-apkdata-download.html

Unfortunately, Modern Combat 4 isn't working normally on Lollipop device, yeah the model will become a pinky object like this.

> [image: Modern Combat 4 Error]

And then I'm doing a quick search on Google just want to know how to fix this, and voila. Maybe you can try this **youtube.com/watch?v=m7qj16vnutM**
To be noted, it's not a promotion, that's not even my YouTube channel nor video, I just want to say that if you want to play this game on your 6.0 device, you can.